# Get response status code from flash Sound object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have music player which downloads and plays music (it should play while downloading), currently my code looks like this:

```
sound = new Sound(new URLRequest(url_stream));
```

Sometimes server returns 404 (Not Found) and 429 (Too many requests) status codes instead of music file, I'm looking for way to find out response status code in case of playback error, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To get the response status, you can use `HTTPStatusEvent` event with an `URLLoader` like this :

```
var sound:Sound
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.example.com/file.mp3')
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
    loader.addEventListener(
        HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, 
        function(event):void {
            trace('http status: ' + event.status)
            if(event.status == 200){
                sound = new Sound(request)
                sound.play()
            }
        }
    )
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(){})
    loader.load(request)
```

This code is working 100%.

Comment: That's for sure, but as I mentioned audio file should be played while downloading, but your code 'loader' will download whole file before I can play it, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In akmozo's solution, you're downloading the MP3 twice. First to see if the file exists on the server, then once more to play it in the Sound. It would be better to do it like this:

```
var sound:Sound;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.example.com/file.mp3');
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var httpCode:int;
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS,loaderStatus);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaderComplete);
function loaderStatus(evt:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
  httpCode = evt.status;
}
function loaderComplete(evt:Event):void {
  if (httpCode == 200) {
    ba:ByteArray = loader.data as ByteArray;
    sound = new Sound();
    sound.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray(ba,ba.length);
    sound.play();
  }
}
```

Although if the URLRequest is cached, maybe it doesn't get downloaded twice.